# ng-repeat suprime duplicate and table format

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a controller like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('PreguntasCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.preguntas = 
  [
    {
        "pregunta_id": "1",
        "pregunta": "Pregunta A",
        "opcion": "1",
    },
    {
        "pregunta_id": "1",
        "pregunta": "Pregunta A",
        "opcion": "2",
    },
    {
        "pregunta_id": "1",
        "pregunta": "Pregunta A",
        "opcion": "3",
    },
    {
        "pregunta_id": "2",
        "pregunta": "Pregunta B",
        "opcion": "1",
    },
    {
        "pregunta_id": "2",
        "pregunta": "Pregunta B",
        "opcion": "2",
    },
    {
        "pregunta_id": "2",
        "pregunta": "Pregunta B",
        "opcion": "3",
    },
    {
        "pregunta_id": "3",
        "pregunta": "Pregunta C",
        "opcion": "1",
    },
    {
        "pregunta_id": "3",
        "pregunta": "Pregunta C",
        "opcion": "2",
    },
    {
        "pregunta_id": "3",
        "pregunta": "Pregunta C",
        "opcion": "3",
    }    
  ]

});
```

I'm using ng-repeat to create a dynamic table, like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in preguntas">        

    <td>
      <span ng-bind="obj.pregunta_id"></span>
    </td>

    <td>
      <span ng-bind="obj.pregunta"></span>
    </td>

    <td>
      <span ng-bind="obj.opcion"></span>
    </td>

</tr>
```

but I need to create the following table:

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td colspan="3">Pregunta A</td>          
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td colspan="3">Pregunta D</td>          
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td colspan="3">Pregunta C</td>          
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
```

I need a way to eliminate duplicating the values **pregunta_id** and **pregunta**, dynamically

I need to show only once and not 3 times

Comment: map your data using vanilla js or `angular.forEach` or lodash or whatever way is easiest into a new structure grouped by `pregunta`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [angular-filter's groupBy](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby).

It provides a filter to help group columns like that:

```
$scope.players = [
  {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'},
  {name: 'George', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma'},
  {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma'}
];
```

--

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | groupBy: 'team'">
    Group name: {{ key }}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="player in value">
        player: {{ player.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<!-- result:
  Group name: alpha
    * player: Gene
  Group name: beta
    * player: George
    * player: Paula
  Group name: gamma
    * player: Steve
    * player: Scruath
-->
```

---

Otherwise you will have to map the data yourself:

```
$scope.preguntas = 
  [
    {
        "pregunta_id": "1",
        "pregunta": "Pregunta A",
        "opcion": ["1", "2", "3"]
    },
    {
        "pregunta_id": "2",
        "pregunta": "Pregunta B",
        "opcions": ["1", "2", "3"]
    }
];
```

--

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="obj in preguntas">
  <td ng-bind="obj.pregunta_id"></td>
  <td colspan="3" ng-bind="obj.pregunta></td>          
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end>
  <td ng-repeat="opcion in obj.opcions" ng-bind="opcion"></td>
</tr>
```